Using reducibility to prove a language that accepts $\lambda$ and either loops or accepts other strings is undecidable
I am new to the reduction style of proof so I am hoping to get some help on this problem.
Let $L=\{〈M〉:M$ accepts the empty string and does not reject any string$\}$. Prove $L$ is undecidable.
My initial approach begins with recognising $A_{TM}$ is reducible to $L$ and assuming $L$ is reducible. So we take a TM $R$ that decides $L$ and use it in a construction of a second TM $S$ that decides $A_{TM}$. However I am unsure how to account for the fact that $M \in L$ doesn't reject any strings, it either accepts or loops.
I feel like the idea follows the standard approach for these sorts of problems, though I'm stuck on whether accounting for the lack of rejection is best done by constructing a modified machine, or if using some kind of mapping reduction is the way to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

A better approach in this case might be a reduction of the following problem
$$A_\lambda = \{\langle M \rangle : M \text{ accepts the empty word}\}$$
which is known to be undecidable.

Hint:

 For a TM $M$, define $M'$ to be the TM that simulates $M$ on $\lambda$ and loops on any other input. Obviously $\langle M' \rangle$ is computable from $\langle M \rangle$. What is the relationship between $\langle M \rangle \in A_\lambda$ and $\langle M' \rangle \in L$?


Thank you for that, that helped make the road clearer!
